# Windows 8 front jack not working and speaker issue

Tags: windows-8, audio, drivers

I previously use windows 7, and everything working fine. My computer can detect headphone and speaker from both of rear and front jack (the green one).

After that, I upgrade my OS to windows 8 professional. This is where the nightmare began. The front jack is suddenly not working, and I can’t detect anything from it. My current speaker, which is plugged in the rear jack, also starts making an annoying sound. It’s just like the CPU sound.

I have tried to uninstall the driver, install it again, update it, etc but none is working.(Via **device manager**)

My driver is (from **dxdiag**) : `HdAudio.sys` provided by **Microsoft**

In the **device manager**, it says that the location is in **location 2**, I don't know what this means.

***Location : Location 2 (Internal High Definition Audio Bus)***

Desperately, i tried to install the **realtek** audio driver, but its not working.

Comment: ehm... how to post the image in the comment?or theres no way for me to post an image? :D

Comment: Upload the image somewhere and post a link to it.

Comment: @BlazeTama Can you confirm that when you did your re-installation you didn't make any hardware changes or even open the case? It's possible that it's been disabled in the BIOS

Comment: @DaveRook Thanks for your response :D Yes, i dont do anything...BUT i accidently installed a windows 8 RP (release preview, not stable) before i install windows 8 RTM.

Comment: Yes, but you then reformatted and installed W8 RTM I assume? Please check the BIOS to ensure that nothing is disabled. Also, does device manager show any faults (yellow !)

Comment: @DaveRook No, i dont format my computer. Ok i will googling about the bios, do you have a tutorial how to do that?My device manager is very normal, it just like everything is working fine :D Thanks

Comment: No, I can't provide a tutorial on the BIOS, you would have to do some research I'm afraid. If you've only just done this installation and don't have many programs / files yet, it could be worth while just reformatting again with W8 RTM